# Move a file from a SharePoint library to a UNC path

Tags: c#, sharepoint, unc

I have a number of files in a document library in SharePoint and the URL paths to those files.  I want to be able to move the files from SharePoint to a UNC path location but  `File.Exists()` and `File.Move()` doesn't work with URL's.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question because I wasn't able to find any specific answer to this.  I found something called DavWWWRoot that allows you to access files through Windows Explorer.

I created the method that converts my URL's into a form that allows me to use File.Move() on the files in my SharePoint Library.

```
private string ConvertSharePointURLToUNCPath(string sharePointFileURL)
    {
        return sharePointFileURL.Replace(@"http://mySharePointSite/", @"\\mySharePointSite\DavWWWRoot\").Replace('/', '\\');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/560c8c91-db98-49a9-aae6-439436e4f933/copy-document-from-sharepoint-to-network-share?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy) an example that iterates through the objects in an SPFileCollection

```
string networkShareURN = @"\\yourserver\sharefolder";

SPSite site = new SPSite("yoursitecollection");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("sitename");
SPFolder myfolder = web.GetFolder("Shared Documents");
SPFileCollection myfiles = myfolder.Files;
foreach (SPFile file in myfiles)
{
     Byte[] bfile = file.OpenBinary();
     System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(networkShareURN + file.Name, bfile);
}
```